# How to select the group that represents an action in the most parsimonious way

Tags: group-theory

On a tweet from a mathematician:

> Students: Why is it upside down 'A' but backwards 'E'?
>
> Me: 'Actually they are both upside down and backwards.'

Many comments, cheesy gifs... and then, some intriguing reply: simply, 'R2?' To which the author of the original tweet responds, 'In my head it's D4 because of the way the question is posed, but yeah, it's really just R2.'

Which answer summarizes the rotation by 180 degrees in a more succinct (parsimonious?) way R2 or D4? The former seems to imply an infinity number of elements given by any angular rotation, whereas the latter implies more than one type of action (rotation and flipping).

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear (for example, in your last sentence, if you use a $180°$ to turn upside down an "A", why would you need a a supplementary flipping ?) A point of vocabulary: for a non native english speaker like me, "cheesy gifs" is not quite understandable. I would be grateful to you,if you explain  what you mean by that ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. As it is often the case, Twitter is full of memes to express emotions, and some of them are of dubious taste. I meant to say, that in that tweeter post there is a lot of junk in the answers, but one stands out as being serious (in my post). I didn't want to include the link so that people who know the mathematician who posted it didn't feel inhibited.

Comment: $D_4$ is an $8$-elements group containing the two elements group $S_2$ as a subgroup. On a basis of simplicity, it looks preferable to use the latter...